# Transforming multiple entries of data for the same ID into a row-awk

Tags: awk

I have data in the following format:

```
ID Date     X1 X2 X3
1  01/01/00 1  2  3
1  01/02/00 7  8  5
2  01/03/00 9  7  1
2  01/04/00 1  4  5
```

I would like to group measurements into new rows according to ID, so I end up with:

```
ID Date     X1 X2 X3 Date   X1_2 X2_2 X3_2
1  01/01/00 1  2  3 01/02/00 7  8  5
2  01/03/00 9  7  1 01/04/00 1  4  5
```

etc.

I have as many as 20 observations for a given ID.

So far I have tried the technique given by http://gadgetsytecnologia.com/da622c17d34e6f13e/awk-transpose-childids-column-into-row.html

The code I have tried so far is:

```
awk -F, OFS = '\t' 'NR >1  {a[$1] = a[$1]; a[$2] = a[$2]; a[$3] = a[$3];a[$4] = a[$4]; a[$5] = a[$5] OFS $5} END {print "ID,Date,X1,X2,X3,Date_2,X1_2, X2_2 X3_2'\t' for (ID in a) print a[$1:$5] }' file.txt
```

The file is a tab delimited file. I don't know how to manipulate the data, or to account for the fact that there will be more than two observations per person.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of what was the previous first field. If it changes, print the stored line:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; next}  # print header
     prev && $1!=prev {print prev, line; line=""}   # print on different $1
     {prev=$1; $1=""; line=line $0}                 # store data and remove $1
     END {print prev, line}' file                   # print trailing line
```

If you have tab-separated fields, just add `-F"\t"`.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print; next} prev && $1!=prev {print prev, line; line=""} {prev=$1; $1=""; line=line $0} END {print prev, line}' a
ID Date     X1 X2 X3
1   01/01/00 1  2  3  01/02/00 7  8  5
2   01/03/00 9  7  1  01/04/00 1  4  5
```

Comment: /me wondering if `gsub("^" $1 FS,"");` is fine. Any better way to remove the first field?

Comment: `$1=""` which keeps the FS in place, so I think you can just merge with `line=line $0` as well.

Comment: @karakfa not really. Test `echo "hello how are you" | awk '{$1=""; print}'` and you'll see a leading FS is left.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.  It will keep the FS in so you can change `line=line FS $0` with `line=line $0`

Comment: @karakfa aaah that's very clever, now I understand it. Thanks, updating my answer : )

Comment: When I run that on my data file, I end up with the last record for each ID showing. Could you please explain how the code you give can append the other records to the end of the same line?

Comment: @Storm the key point is in storing the data with the same id in `line`. It keeps adding content until a new id appears. Regarding what happens to you: not sure what you mean, you may want to update your question giving the input you are using, the output and how it differs to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this (gnu-awk solution)

```
gawk '
  NR == 1 {
    N = NF;
    MAX = NF-1;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){  #store columns names
      names[i]=$i;
    }
    next;
  }
  {
    for(i=2; i<=N; i++){
      a[$1][length(a[$1])+1] = $i;  #store records for each id
    }
    if(length(a[$1])>MAX){
      MAX = length(a[$1]);
    }
  }
  END{
    firstline = names[1];
    for(i=1; i<=MAX; i++){          #print first line
      column = int((i-1)%(N-1))+2
      count = int((i-1)/(N-1));
      firstline=firstline OFS names[column];
      if(count>0){
        firstline=firstline"_"count
      }
    }
    print firstline
    for(id in a){          #print each record in store
      line = id;
      for(i=1; i<=length(a[id]); i++){
        line=line OFS a[id][i];
      }
      print line;
    }
  }
' input
```

> input

```
ID Date     X1 X2 X3
1  01/01/00 1  2  3
1  01/02/00 7  8  5
2  01/03/00 9  7  1
2  01/04/00 1  4  5
1  01/03/00 72 28 25
```

you get

```
ID Date     X1 X2 X3 Date_1   X1_1 X2_1 X3_1 Date_2   X1_2 X2_2 X3_2
1  01/01/00 1  2  3  01/02/00 7    8    5    01/03/00 72   28   25
2  01/03/00 9  7  1  01/04/00 1    4    5
```